# Loading... message when running a new standalone Blazor WebAssembly project

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I am very new to Blazor.  I am using Visual Studio 2022.

I have created a brand new C# Blazor WebAssembly *without* the hosted option.

My understanding is that I don't need the hosted option because I am not writing the backend at the same time as the client.  The backend API that my Blazor client will use already exists.

I have done nothing with the new project except build it.  When I run it (Debug > Start New Instance), I am expecting the usual default Hello World page with the Counter and Fetch Data tabs.  However, I get a "Loading..." message only.

I googled and found this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

But the page describes running a hosted WebAssembly project.

So I created a hosted project.  That runs fine.  I get the working page up whether I run the server or the client.

So my question is:

It is possible to run a stand-alone WebAssembly project in Viusual Studio?  Or only a hosted one?

If it's supposed to be possible, what should I be checking to figure out why my standalone project will not run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to run it in IISExpress.  I just deployed a Web Assembly application - Net6 and Visual Studio 2022.  My run looks like this:

[image]

Which works:  My Solution was called BlazorApp6.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer.  I did more tests in the morning after some sleep.  It ran fine from dotnet command line.  So I restarted VS and then it was fine.  I'm assuming VS got bunged up somehow and I went down a pointless rabbit hole.  The point is, yes a standalone Blazor app is expected to run from VS which is what you have said.

Comment: NP.  The current VS2022 releases seem to have funny turns all too regularly!!